# Reading XML file from php

Tags: php, xml

I am downloading and reading XML file from email using this code:

```
<?php
require_once("attachmentread.class.php");
$host="{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX"; // pop3host
$login="axxxxxxxx@gmail.com"; //pop3 login
$password="whxxxxxxx"; //pop3 password
$savedirpath="" ; // attachement will save in same directory where scripts run othrwise give abs path
$jk=new readattachment(); // Creating instance of class####
$jk->getdata($host,$login,$password,$savedirpath); // calling member function


$xml=simplexml_load_file("/data/www/Message14.xml");
$message=$xml->TEMPLATE;
$mobile= $xml->MESSAGES->MESSAGE->RECIPIENT_NUM;

$mobile1=str_replace("050", "97150", $mobile); 
?>
```

My original Message14.xml look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<DOCUMENT><VERSION>2.0</VERSION><INVOICE_NUM>30</INVOICE_NUM><PIN>14567894</PIN><MESSAGE_TYPE>INSTANT_SEND</MESSAGE_TYPE><COUNTRY_CODE>971</COUNTRY_CODE><TEMPLATE> Hi xxxxxx
</TEMPLATE><DATABASEINFO><DATABASE_NAME>Sys2000</DATABASE_NAME><CLINIC_ID>1</CLINIC_ID></DATABASEINFO><MESSAGES><MESSAGE><SEND_DATE>2013-07-02</SEND_DATE><ENTITY_ID>0</ENTITY_ID><RECIPIENT_NUM>xxxxxxxxx</RECIPIENT_NUM><MESSAGE_PARAMS/></MESSAGE></MESSAGES><CSUM>dcb4855eccf730e3668a386acaaf7d60</CSUM></DOCUMENT>
```

but now its includeing 3D,ect it looks like this

```
?xml version=3D3D"1.0" ?>
<DOCUMENT><VERSION>2.0</VERSION><INVOICE_NUM>30</INVOICE_NUM><PIN>1456789=
=3D
4</PIN><MESSAGE_TYPE>INSTANT_SEND</MESSAGE_TYPE><COUNTRY_CODE>971</COUNTR=
=3D
Y_CODE><TEMPLATE> Hi xxxxxxxxx
</TEMPLATE><DATABASEINFO><DATABASE_NAME>Sys2000</DATABASE_NAME><CLINIC_ID=
=3D
>1</CLINIC_ID></DATABASEINFO><MESSAGES><MESSAGE><SEND_DATE>2013-07-02</SE=
=3D
ND_DATE><ENTITY_ID>0</ENTITY_ID><RECIPIENT_NUM>0xxxxxxxxx</RECIPIENT_NUM>=
=3D
<MESSAGE_PARAMS/></MESSAGE></MESSAGES><CSUM>dcb4855eccf730e3668a386acaaf7=
=3D
d60</CSUM></DOCUMENT>
```

Can anyone guide me how to download as the original file not inculding 3d .thanks

Comment: The formatting of the XML document, so long as the schema remains the same, should have no bearing on processing, besides extra whitespace. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: new characters add to xml files like 3D3D and =3D

Comment: It seems to be encoded using "quoted-printable", not UTF-8 as stated in the file. Try playing with the quoted_printable_decode function, it might help.

Comment: i removed encoding and tried,it's same 3D3D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrong Content of XML attachment when downloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657104/wrong-content-of-xml-attachment-when-downloading)

Answer (score 1):

The "3D" refers to the character code for an equal sign.  The inclusion of this in your XML code indicates that double encoding or other encoding problems occurred.  You can use PHP's **quoted_printable_decode** function to fix the issue.  [PHP's manual here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php)

You can try: `file_put_contents("/data/www/Message14.xml", quoted_printable_decode(file_get_contents("/data/www/Message14.xml")));`

Put that just before you use the simplexml_load_file function.

Comment: Huh? `simplexml_load_file` returns an object, but `quoted_printable_decode`'s first parameter must be a string.

Comment: Then before the simplexml_load_file string, put something like file_put_contents("/data/www/Message14.xml", quoted_printable_decode(file_get_contents("/data/www/Message14.xml")));